# React Native app error when running with Relay

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I have successfully generated `create-react-native-app` however, when I install `relay` along with `graphql`, I am getting error:

```
> react-native-scripts start

10:50:27 AM: Starting packager...
***ERROR STARTING PACKAGER***
Warning: Problem validating app.json: Unable to perform cache refresh for /home/vagrant/.cache/expo/schema-27.0.0.json: Error: certificate is not yet valid.

Error: Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 10.0.0, 11.0.0, 12.0.0, 13.0.0, 14.0.0, 15.0.0, 16.0.0, 17.0.0, 18.0.0, 19.0.0, 20.0.0, 21.0.0, 22.0.0, 23.0.0, 24.0.0, 25.0.0, 7.0.0, 8.0.0, 9.0.0
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "blah",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-relay": "^1.6.2",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1",
    "relay-compiler": "^1.6.2"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest",
    "relay": "relay-compiler --src ./ --schema ./db/schema.json"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2",
    "react-relay": "^1.6.2"
  }
}
```

**UPDATED**

My app.json has:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "27.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Open your build.gradle file ( located in YOUR_PROJECT/android/app/build.gradle ) and validate your compileSdkVersion

Are you using expo?

Comment: @coderaizer I'm using expo but, not sure how this relates. All I"m doing is starting the project from NPM and getting that error.

Comment: Check sdkVersion in your app.json file and make sure it's same as one in package.json file.

Comment: @coderaizer I've updated my post above and included the app.json.